# Are there any objective benefits to using Nx's Data Persistence functions with NgRx effects?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, nrwl-nx

I have an Angular app and NgRx and Nx by Nrwl. Nx provides a few ["Data Persistence"](https://nx.dev/angular/guides/misc-data-persistence) functions that help you fetch, update optimistically and pessimistically, and handle navigation, but I am not sure why I would use them instead of ordinary pipes.

[Here's an example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-nx-data-persistence) showing some effects with `optimisticUpdate` and `pessimisticUpdate` alongside other effects that do the same thing without them.

The question is - what advantage do these Nx functions provide?

*For reference, here's the effects file from the StackBlitz:*

```js
@Injectable()
export class CarsEffects {
  updateCarOptimistic = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(CarsActions.updateCarOptimistic),
      switchMap(({ selected, oldSelected, mockError }) =>
        this.carsService.updateCar(selected, mockError).pipe(
          map(() => CarsActions.updateCarOptimisticSuccess()),
          catchError(error => {
            this.store.dispatch(
              CarsActions.updateCarOptimisticFailure({ oldSelected, error })
            );
            return of(null);
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );

  updateCarOptimisticWithNx = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(CarsActions.updateCarOptimisticWithNx),
      optimisticUpdate({
        run: ({ selected, mockError }) =>
          this.carsService
            .updateCar(selected, mockError)
            .pipe(map(() => CarsActions.updateCarOptimisticWithNxSuccess())),
        undoAction: ({ oldSelected }, error) =>
          CarsActions.updateCarOptimisticWithNxFailure({ oldSelected, error })
      })
    )
  );

  updateCarPessimistic = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(CarsActions.updateCarPessimistic),
      switchMap(({ selected, mockError }) =>
        this.carsService.updateCar(selected, mockError).pipe(
          map(() => CarsActions.updateCarPessimisticSuccess({ selected })),
          catchError(error =>
            of(CarsActions.updateCarPessimisticFailure({ error }))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

  updateCarPessimisticWithNx = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(CarsActions.updateCarPessimisticWithNx),
      pessimisticUpdate({
        run: ({ selected, mockError }) =>
          this.carsService
            .updateCar(selected, mockError)
            .pipe(
              map(() =>
                CarsActions.updateCarPessimisticWithNxSuccess({ selected })
              )
            ),
        onError: (_, error) =>
          CarsActions.updateCarPessimisticWithNxFailure({ error })
      })
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions: Actions,
    private store: Store,
    private carsService: CarsService
  ) {}
}
```

**NOTE:** I don't mean for this to be a question about matters of opinion on preferable syntax; just wanting to make my code as performant, secure, and clean as possible, and would like to use these functions if they are doing something behind the scenes I am unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you provide an `id` selector function. Check out the examples [here](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/guides/misc-data-persistence#data-fetching). In my own testing, if you dispatch an action multiple times, every request will go through unless you use the `id` selector. Once you add that in, `fetch` will cancel any existing network requests if a new action comes through with the same ID.

This functionality can be obtained with a simple `switchMap` operator, but the `fetch` utility has another advantage that `switchMap` doesn't provide: dispatching an action with a *different* ID while a network request is in progress will not cancel the current request.

Consider the following example:

```
this.store.dispatch(getUser('AAA'));
this.store.dispatch(getUser('BBB'));
this.store.dispatch(getUser('AAA'));
```

With `switchMap`, only the last request would go through, so you would never successfully fetch user `BBB`. With `fetch`, however, the last **two** requests would go through.